# No log file can be found with lombok

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback, lombok

I want to output some information to the log file with lombok, but there is no log file in the path I specified, and there is no output from the IDEA console.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>xdclass-cloud</artifactId>
        <groupId>net.xdclass</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>xdclass-common</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

resource/logback-spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false">
    <property name="LOG_HOME" value="E:/logs" />
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/TestWeb.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
            <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

App.java:

```
package net.my.domain;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@Slf4j
public class App {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("logback 111");
        logger.error("logback 222");
        logger.debug("logback 333");
        }
}
```

I have specified the log path `<property name="LOG_HOME" value="E:/logs" />`,I don’t know where is wrong, there is no file in path `E:/logs`.

IDEA's console also has no output,I think there should be 3 lines in the console, like this:

```
logback 111
logback 222
logback 333
```

Comment: IDK if it will solve your problem but you have some problems with your `App` class, as you have it annotated with `@Slf4j` you don't need to declare your `logger` variable, you can just type `log.info("logback 111")`, you can read the more here https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/extern/slf4j/Slf4j.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using in your pom.xml `slf4j-nop`, which is a no-op version of slf4j, which doesn't log anything.
You need to add to your pom logback if you want to use that.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, as @MarcosBarbero commented above - if you are using the `@Slf4j` annotation, you don't need to instantiate the logger. lombok will generate a `log` field for you.

Answer (score 0):

As Nir Levy said,the right `pom.xml` should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>xdclass-cloud</artifactId>
        <groupId>net.xdclass</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>xdclass-common</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And the App.java should be:

```
package net.xdclass.domain;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@Slf4j
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("logback 111");
        log.error("logback 222");
        log.debug("logback 333");
        }
}
```